# Does function parameter allow static specifier?

Tags: c++, c, static

Premises:
No specific reason. Just newbie checking for completeness for `static` usage.

I am just searching for the quote in the standard that forbid static parameter. (and possible reasons)

I am trying out below code but the compiler fails:

```
void function(static int i) {
    static int num_call = 0;
    cout << "At " << num_call << "-th call, argument value is: " << i << endl;
}
```

This is just for theoretical syntax discussion.

**Edits:**

ISO C11 6.7.6.3 paragraph 2: "The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is register." –  Keith Thompson 24 mins ago

Comment: What purpose do you think a static parameter would serve?

Comment: I know it doesn't make really much sense, but can't the guy just ask without get downvote? who knows the real reason why he's asking that? he might be just confusing in something like this: to pass a variable like this `static int x;` in a function `int f(int x) { ... }` you need to put `static` in the `x` too: `int f(static int x){ ... }`

Comment: @jaymmer I wrote it there. Just read it: (possible reasons) ... for theoretical syntax discussion

Comment: There's absolutely no good reason, if it were possible, to make `i` `static`.  It's value would change every function call.  `num_call` would serve a purpose, if you remember to increment it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ANSI C89 standard, section 3.5.4.3 Function declarators, can be found:

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter
>   declaration is register.

which means in practice that function arguments are passed either on the stack, or in registers. (They may be passed in registers even without the "register" storage class.) I cannot think of a reason why one might want to pass an argument in static storage - it seems to make no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

No. It doesn't. The only storage class that can be used with parameters is `register`.

**C11: 6.7.6.3 Function declarators:**

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is **`register`**.

Comment: And `register` is not particularly useful (modern compilers are better at deciding what variables should be in registers than most programmers are).

Comment: @KeithThompson; Yes. Without ant doubt.

Comment: What about `auto`, not that that is particularly useful either.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, Not as of C++11, but I guess so, yes.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: ISO C11 6.7.6.3 paragraph 2: "The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is **`register`**."